# Accessing values inside eventReactive

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

I need help with a basic Shiny question. My goal is to make a simple math quiz app (What is 4 x 4?). I want to create values with one button, select a numeric answer, and then press another answer button. My problem is that i cannot find a way to access the values that are stored inside eventReactive. I have simplified the problem in the code below. The goal of this app is to ask for a number, and then to supply it. Thank you in advance!

```
# Goal: Fetch a number, then input that number, then receive paste("correct")/paste("incorrect)

ui <- fluidPage(
      textOutput(outputId = "out"),

      numericInput(inputId = "inn",
               label = "",
               value = 0),

  actionButton("answer", "Answer"),
  actionButton("question", "New Question"),
)




server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- eventReactive(input$question,{

    a <- sample.int(10,1)

    paste("Enter",a)

    })

  output$out <- renderText({data()})

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Happy to help, but I struggle to understand what the app is supposed to do. Can you clarify on the role of the `numericInput` and two `actionButton`s? Perhaps give a simple event breakdown of the form: User must do A. Then B happens. Then user presses button C. Then D happens...

Comment: Thank you! It's a lot simpler. User A (the only user) press a button to get a randomly selected  number. then user A selects that number with inputNumeric. Then user A press the Answer button. If its the same number then there is some feedback ("Correct")/("Wrong"). 

My problem is that when i store values inside eventReactive (Question button), then i cannot refer to that value from another eventReactive (Answer button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do

```r
ui <- fluidPage(

      textOutput(outputId = "out"),
      numericInput(inputId = "inn", label = "", value = 0),
      actionButton("answer", "Answer"),
      actionButton("question", "New Question"),

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    data <- reactiveValues(number = NULL)

    output$out <- renderText({
        if (is.null(data$number))
            "Press 'New Question' button"
        else
            paste("Enter", data$number)
    })

    observeEvent(input$question, {
        data$number = sample(10, 1)
     })

    observeEvent(input$answer, {
        req(data$number, input$inn)
        if (data$number == input$inn)
            print("Correct")
            # Do something exciting
        else
            print("Incorrect")
            # Do something else
    })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

IMO it's good practice to keep reactive data and input/output generation separate. What I mean by that is that in the above example we use

- `reactiveValues` to keep track of the changing data, and
- `observeEvent` to monitor button clicks which may change specific elements of our reactive data,
- `renderText` can print either fixed text or reactive data.

Comment: This is perfect! I just learned a ton about reactiveValues and using reactive data. Thank you Maurits!